# Debugging values in .NET framework source debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, frameworks, f#

I've enabled .NET framework source debugging in VS2010 (Premium, if it matters), and I can step through the methods inside .NET framework DLLs, but most values I can't read or poke around in and all I get is a red exclamation mark and a text that says:

> Cannot obtain value of local or
>   argument 'skipJournaledProperties' as
>   it is not available at this
>   instruction pointer, possibly because
>   it has been optimized away.

Example:

[image: Framework]

Is there any way to enable reading of these values?